# Split XML file into multiple files with 500 tags each

Tags: java, xml, split, stax

I have a large (1 GB) file that I need to split into smaller files. I want each smaller file to contain 500 of the `<OFFER>` tags.

Here is a small snippet of the large XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?><RESULT>
<header>
    <site>http://www.thomascook.fr</site>
    <marque>ThomasCook France</marque>
    <logo>http://www.example.com/example.gif</logo>
</header>
<OFFER>
    <IFF>5810</IFF>
    <TO>TCF</TO>
    <COUNTRY>Chypre</COUNTRY>
    <REGION>Chypre du Sud</REGION>
    <HOTELNAME>Elias Beach &amp; Country Club</HOTELNAME>
    <DESCRIPTION>....</DESCRIPTION>
    <TYPE>Sejour</TYPE>
    <STARS>5.0</STARS>
    <THEMAS>Plage directe;Special enfant;Bien-Etre-Fitness</THEMAS>
    <THUMBNAIL>http://example.com/example.jpg</THUMBNAIL>
    <URL>http://example.com/example.html</URL>
    <DATE>
        <BROCHURE>TCFB</BROCHURE>
        <DURATION>7</DURATION>
        <DURATION_VAR>6_6-9</DURATION_VAR>
        <BOARD>Demi-pension</BOARD>
        <DEPARTURE>27.2.2011</DEPARTURE>
        <RETURN>6.3.2011</RETURN>
        <DEPARTURE_CITY>PAR</DEPARTURE_CITY>
        <ARRIVAL_CITY>LCA</ARRIVAL_CITY>
        <PRICE>790</PRICE>
        <URL>http://example.com/other-example.html</URL>
    </DATE>
</OFFER>
<OFFER>
  (etc)
</OFFER>
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Please indent your XML so that we can read it.

Comment: What programming language are you using (or able to use)?

Answer (score 2):

From you english I understand that you want to split a big XML file into multiple small files. The best one is http://vtd-xml.sourceforge.net/

Sample Code, the following code will split the big xml based on XPath, TopTag/ChildTag

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

import com.ximpleware.AutoPilot;
import com.ximpleware.FastLongBuffer;
import com.ximpleware.VTDGen;
import com.ximpleware.VTDNav;

// This example shows how to split XML
public class Split {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String prefix = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" standalone=\"yes\"?>\n<TopTag xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\">\n";
        String suffix = "\n</TopTag<";
        try {

            VTDGen vg = new VTDGen();
            if (vg.parseFile(args[0], false)) {
                int splitBy = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
                String filePrefix =  args[2];
                VTDNav vn = vg.getNav();
                AutoPilot ap = new AutoPilot(vn);
                ap.selectXPath("/TopTag/ChildTag");
                // flb contains all the offset and length of the segments to be
                // skipped
                FastLongBuffer flb = new FastLongBuffer(4);
                int i;
                byte[] xml = vn.getXML().getBytes();
                while ((i = ap.evalXPath()) != -1) {
                    flb.append(vn.getElementFragment());
                }
                int size = flb.size();
                if (size != 0) {
                    File fo = null;
                    FileOutputStream fos = null;
                    for (int k = 0; k < size; k++) {
                        if (k % splitBy == 0) {
                            if (fo != null) {
                                fos.write(suffix.getBytes());
                                fos.close();
                                fo = null;
                            }
                        }
                        if (fo == null) {
                            fo = new File(filePrefix + k + ".xml");
                            fos = new FileOutputStream(fo);
                            fos.write(prefix.getBytes());
                        }
                        fos.write(xml, flb.lower32At(k), flb.upper32At(k));
                    }
                    if (fo != null) {
                        fos.write(suffix.getBytes());
                        fos.close();
                        fo = null;
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: My understanding is that vdt-xml works by loading the entire XML document into memory.  While it claims to use memory efficiently, even by its own estimates this could require up to 1.5Gb of heap for a 1Gb XML document.

Answer (score 2):

As a programming question, this is just a matter of stax *programming*.

Every 500 elements make the necessary calls to end the element and the document, close the file, open a new file, start the new file, and continue along. If you have a program that can write one file in stax, it's not very different to write many.